# Set focus to an element when another element has focus with ng-focus

Tags: angularjs, keyboard, tabindex

I have angularJS application.There are two components left nav bar and right side content pane.When I go to the end of the right side content pane with tab(keyboard) it gives the focus to the browser URL bar.But I need to give the tab(keyboard) focus to the left nav bar or just need to stop focus getting in to url.

..below is the end of the content pane

```
<div>
   <ul>                
       <li class="seperater">
                <a href="" ng-focus="navigateToTop();">test navigate </a>               
       </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

What I tried is when focus came to the final element on the content page ,call a method 'navigateToTop' and there I set focus to left nav.

below is the method

```
this.navigateToTop = function () {

        console.log("in navigateToTop");
        $('#left-nav').focus();

    };
```

But it is not working and still focusing to the URL.Pls help..

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time I found the solution by doing some changes to my html code of the right content pane.

```
<div>
  <ul>                
     <li class="seperater">
            <a href="" ng-focus="isFocused = true" ng-blur="isFocused = false">
        test navigate </a>               
     </li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-if="navigateToTop(isFocused);"></div>
</div>
```